# What is a string in Go?

Tags: go

Is a `string` in Go is like a `char*` in C (or a `char[]`) or a class `string` in C++... or something else?

I don't understand how a string can be a primitive type.

Comment: Fast google search gave this: http://golang.org/pkg/strings/

Comment: yes, but it didn't answer my question

Comment: To answer your question it would be interesting which problem you see in a string as primitive type.

Comment: For me, primitive types are the basic types (``char``, ``int``...etc and pointers) which have a definite size in memory (ex: ``int`` -> 4 bytes).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A string in go is represented [by this structure](http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/runtime.h#L173) in C

```
struct String
{
    byte*   str;
    intgo   len;
};
```

The `str` pointer points to the actual string data but this is not null terminated - the length is held in the `len` member.

So in C terms a go string is a long way from a primitive type, it is a pointer, a length and an area of memory.

However Go is not C and all of those implementation details are invisible to Go programs.  In Go a string **is** a primitive immutable type.

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation for the type `string`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#string) says:

> string is the set of all strings of 8-bit bytes, conventionally but not necessarily representing UTF-8-encoded text. A string may be empty, but not nil. Values of string type are immutable.

They are immutable, which would seem to make them less like the C concepts you compare to, and more like maybe a `const char []` where the `const` really means `const`.

Anything can be a primitive type in a programming language, it's up to the designers. "Being a primitive" doesn't have to mean actually being, you know, primitive. :)

Comment: In a similar vein, Go's channels are implemented with small data structures. You don't /need/ to know what's in those structures in order to use channels effectively. The same can also be said about Go's maps, even though these are different because they're mutable.